# Rust: Как передать gRPC-клиента в State (общие данные)

Tags: rust, grpc, actix-web

Изучаю Rust.
Gateway на Actix-Web.
Можно ли поместить grpc-клиента в State приложения и затем дергать его в handler'ах?
Чтобы не создавать его в каждом handler'е.
Если можно, то как это сделать?

`[main.rs]`

```
#[actix_rt::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let channel = Channel::from_static("http://127.0.0.1:5051")
    .connect()
    .await.unwrap();

    let token = AsciiMetadataValue::from_static("...");
    let mut user_client = UserServiceClient::with_interceptor(channel, move |mut req: Request<()>| {
        req.metadata_mut().insert("authorization", token);
        Ok(req)
    });
    let shared_data = web::Data::new(State {
        user_client: user_client,
    });

    let app = move || {
    App::new()
       .app_data(shared_data.clone()) ...
...
}
```

`[user_handler.rs]`

```
pub async fn get_users(path: web::Path<(i64,i64)>, state: web::Data<State>,) -> Result<HttpResponse, AppError> {
    let request = tonic::Request::new(...);
    let mut client = UserServiceClient::connect("http://127.0.0.1:5051").await?;
    let mut grpc_response = client.list_users(request).await?.into_inner();
    let json_response: UsersListResponse = grpc_response.into();
    Ok(HttpResponse::Ok().json(json_response))
}
```

`[state.rs]`

```
pub struct State {
    pub user_client: UserServiceClient<InterceptedService<Channel, fn(Request<()>) -> Result<Request<()>, Status>>>,
}
```

[image: Ошибка в State]